# Disable/Delete Azure Boards Team Board

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a setup of three teams in Azure DevOps, but I only want to use one backlog/dashboard for all teams. Therefor I want to disable or delete the unsued team dashboards created by default.

It´s really handy to manage the tickets and teams via areas for each team, so every team can only see the related tickets in the "main" dashboard.

I read the documentation, searched for similar topics here and wasted a lot of time to search for the solution in DevOps.

Does anyone know how to delete/disable a team board if it´s not used or is it not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your case the guidance would be to create a single team and manually setup the Area paths. That way you get a single Kanban board, a single backlog and a single dashboard.

Comment: Worked perfectly. These settings are located in `Project Settings > Boards > Team configuration > Areas`.

Answer (score -1):

To delete team dashboard you could try this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/rest/api/azure/devops/dashboard/dashboards/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboardId}?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

But, when there is only one dashboard in your team, you can't delete the only one.So, it is not feasible to delete all other team's dashboards.

Comment: Thanks Hugh Lin, I also figured that out.